# SHA-256 hashing in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

How can i encrypt or hash a password inside a trigger using sha-256 so that i can store the hashed value in another table using that trigger? Also how can I decrypt it??

Comment: Why are you sending a plain text password in the first place?

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately `DBMS_CRYPTO` in Oracle 11.2 only supports SHA1 ([documentation link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_crypto.htm#ARPLS65674)), which is 160-bit. .

`DBMS_CRYPTO` in Oracle 12.1 supports SHA2 `HASH_SH256` ([documentation link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17602/d_crypto.htm#ARPLS65671)), which does what you require.

There are some free implementations of SHA2 just a google away. [This blog post](http://jakub.wartak.pl/blog/?p=124), for example.

As for decrypting a hashed password? I don't think you understand hashing. Hashing is 1-way, unless you brute-force it, or use [Rainbow Tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table). To check if a password is correct, you would hash it and compare it to the stored hash.

Answer (score 3):

My impimentation using sha256 pack

```
  Function hmac_sha256
  (
    ptext Varchar2,
    pkey  Varchar2
  ) Return Varchar2
 Is
    -- pad const
    c_opad      Raw(1) := '5c';
    c_ipad      Raw(1) := '36';
    c_kpad      Raw(1) := '00';

    --SHA256 block size 512 bit
    c_blocksize Integer := 64;

    --local var, length equals to blocksize
    l_opad        Raw(64);
    l_ipad        Raw(64);
    l_key         Raw(64);
  Begin

    l_opad := utl_raw.copies(c_opad, c_blocksize);
    l_ipad := utl_raw.copies(c_ipad, c_blocksize);

    If utl_raw.length(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(pkey)) > c_blocksize Then
      l_key := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(sha256.encrypt(pkey));
    Else
      l_key := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(pkey);
    End If;

    l_key := l_key ||
             utl_raw.copies(c_kpad, c_blocksize - utl_raw.length(l_key));

    Return sha256.encrypt_raw(utl_raw.bit_xor(l_key, l_opad) ||
                              sha256.encrypt_raw(utl_raw.bit_xor(l_key, l_ipad) || utl_raw.cast_to_raw(ptext))
                              );

  End;
```

Comment: How do you implement this?